# Save and reset values from drop down list

Tags: javascript

I have drop down list, after select value from it I push the button and some calculations are made. I save value from list by this:

```
     <select name="dropDownTo" id="dropDownTo">
        <option value="Yard">Yard</option>
            <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
        <option value="Metre">Metre</option>
     </select>                          

    <button onclick="MyFunc()">Update</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("dropDownTo").onchange = function() {
         localStorage['dropDownTo'] = document.getElementById("dropDownTo").value;
        }
    function MyFunc(){
        document.getElementById("dropDownTo").value = localStorage['dropDownTo'];

        window.onload  = document.getElementById("dropDownTo").value;
        alert(document.getElementById("dropDownTo").value);
    }
</script>
```

But the select value stay selected after closing the window. Is it possible restore default value after closing the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should run an action before the page exits, restoring the value to its default. There is a javascript event for that. [Window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return 'You are leaving this page';
}
```

Comment: Read the API. It works the same way you run your `.onchange` function.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a value as selected will initially select that value every time the page is loaded:

```
<option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
```